# 08 GMC Canyon automatic 4l60e won't engage when shifted from park into drive, but will engage if shifted from park to 1st

Tags: transmission, shifting, gmc, canyon

I have a 08 GMC Canyon 4x4 automatic transmission 4l60e that when shifted from Park into Drive it won't Engage but if shifted from park to 1st it will engage. The transmission won't go when shifted from Park to Drive but will go if manually shifted from Park to 1st.

Once I get going after manually shifting from Park to 1st I then can shift it into Drive and it will automatically shift up and down with no problem other than when I slow down to about 10mph or come to a stop, when it will act like it's in Neutral so then I have to manually put it in 1st get going and then shift it back into Drive.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the amount of fluid in the transmission? If so, how does the fluid look/smell?